# Joomla Menu Link SEF

Tags: joomla, menu, hyperlink

My main menu resides over the entire site. It is a guide with quick links to get them in the right general area.

I have a site that has multiple campuses.

Campus 1, Campus 2, Campus 3, Campus 4

Under Each Campus in the drop down menu there are two main links.

So the menu looks like this:

CAMPUS1
      main link 1
      main link 2

etc.

Now once you get to the Campus1 > Main Link 1 Article there are tons of links to different events going on in that campus.

My question, finally, is how do I create a link to those events without it showing up in the menu dropdown yet still keeping the SEO file structure.

Example:
website.com/campus1/mainlink1/event1

There may be several "event1" at different campuses so I can't make a Hidden Menu with those links because then the link becomes websitename.com/event1 and that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the depth that a menu will display.  It's a setting in the menu module.  So you could have those events in the menu, and still not displayed.